# How can I efficiently browse through extends and implements in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

The idea of polymorphism sounds great on paper. In real life someone joins a new project and starts working on this code:

```
class Tom extends Cat implements Male {
temperature temperature = Tom.getTemperature();
..............
class Cat extends Feline{
..............
class Feline extends Mammals{
..............
class Mammals extends Animals implements WarmBlooded{
....... 
interface WarmBlooded{
int temperature=96; //In case they forget to set the right temperature...
public int getTemperature(){
return temperature;
}
```

Compare to

```
Cat cat = new Cat(Tom, m, 96);
```

and

```
class Cat(Stiing name, char gender, int temperature){
    ....
}
```

Sure, we saved a couple of lines of code by implementing `WarmBlooded`, but at what cost? We have to look through multiple classes just to find out what `getTemperature()` is doing - isn't this an example of a spaghetti code? Millions of coders chose Java. There must be a reason for polymorphism. I will anyway have to keep in mind name, gender and temperature of a cat I am creating. Implementing `Male` is no different than passing "m" as a parameter when creating Tom. Why not bundle everything in `Cat`?

Does it mean I should read and understand the whole project to start benefiting from polymorphism? Are there any methods to make browsing through extends/implements easier?

---

What does efficiently browse through extends/implements mean?
It means "can find out what this method is doing in reasonable time".

Comment: What does efficiently browse through extends/implements mean?

Comment: There are loads of tools to visualise class hierarchies (not to mention the support you get in IDEs like Idea/Eclipse/Netbeans), but a well-designed class hierarchy with adequate documentation should be very easy to traverse. The whole point of abstractions like polymorphism is to reduce the overall complexity, and thus the amount of code you need to read through to understand what a class does.

Comment: A decent Java IDE provides various helpful views and accelerators for dealing with this kind of thing.  Try one.

Comment: `implements WarmBlooded` and `abstract class WarmBlooded` won't work.

Comment: Proper documentation and comments in professional atmosphere mitigates these issues. IMHO

Comment: "Are there any methods to make browsing through extends/implements easier?" Are you referring to something like a [UML class diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram)?

Comment: javadoc javadoc javadoc

Comment: The problem with `implements WarmBlooded` is not that the class was abstract: you don't *implement* a class, you *extend* it; you implement an `interface`.

Comment: If you’re looking for something like [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/package-tree.html), you can generate it yourself with [the javadoc tool that comes with every JDK](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/).

Comment: I will try IDE. I was using Notepad++. It worked for scripting languages, but doesn't seem to be enough for Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use IDE. Such as NetBeans or Eclipse. Also, use UML. Otherwise it is hard to follow the code. It allows you to click on getTemperature() to see the implementation.

```
 Class Feline is useless if it only holds   
    Boolean isFeline = true;
```

However, if it holds multiple methods it makes life easier - you don't have to keep in mind all these methods.

Java works best for larger projects. Joining such projects can be more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

First: `WarmBlooded` is an abstract class; you should be `extend`ing it, not `implement`ing it.

The point of inheritance and polymorphism is to create a more easily extensible project. If you find yourself creating parent classes and interfaces simply for the sake of doing so, then yes, that's spaghetti code.

But when a project is going to involve lots of different classes (in your example, animals) then having a pre-defined contract the animals must fulfill or behavior that is already implemented is incredibly useful because it:

1. In the case of an interface or abstract class with abstract methods, forces the programmer to fulfill a particular contract (e.g, by implementing the `eat()` method for an animal
2. In the case of existing methods, saves the programmer time as well as ensuring they don't mistakenly put different behavior in different animals when they intended the same behavior. For example, if you had to rewrite `getTemperature` for every animal, your more prone to error - and if you ever want to *change* the behavior, you have to change it in several places.

As others said, a good IDE (or even familiarity with your text editor) makes working with this paradigm fairly easy.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is the classical inheritance (Animal, Cat, Dog) from the dawn of inheritance. However inheritance does not really suit all aspects, like your polymorphism.

An alternative:

```
interface Swimming {
    double getSwimmingSpeed();
    void swim();
}

interface Flying {
    void fly();
}

class Animal {
    public <T> Optional<T> lookup(Class<T> type);
}

// Class or instance:
Animal pelikan = ...
Optional<Swimming> swimming = pelikan.lookup(Swimming.class);
swimming.ifPresent(::swim);

Animal flyingFish = ...
Optional<Flying> flying = flyingFish.lookup(Flying.class);

// lookup might use a Map<Class<?>, ?>.
```

This approach uses a discovery mechanism to lookup capabilities, features. This is better than the polymorphism above, implementing several interfaces, as it decouples classes, and the implementing code (class) can be reused.

However it also hides the capabilities, as they are dynamic. You would not know by reading the classes, that some fish could fly.

But most important, it can reduce the number of classes that only exist to represent instances with different capabilities. There often is no need for a sepearate class FlyingFish, with some specific constructor.